# Bash: value too great for base (string with numbers)

Tags: bash

It looks like this is a common problem but I didn't see a solution that would work well for my specific scenario:

My script takes a number of arguments, which are strings with leading numbers. The script then loops through an input stream line by line looking to see if the user's arguments are contained within the input stream. Unfortunately, I receive an error with my if statement e.g.

...value too great for base (error token is "21000E1E06F54F")...

```
#get user arguments
MyArray+=($OPTARG)

#for each array element, loop through an input looking for the string 
read <&3
if [[ $REPLY == *${MyArray[$i]}* ]]; then 
  found=1
fi
```

An example of an argument would be: 21000E1E06F54F, but I'm hesitant to say it will always be hex - I'd rather just treat it as a string. Obviously, I can put a letter before $OPTARG but then the string comparison is off or I would need to add code to workaround the added letter. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I was hoping there would be some simple syntax I could add to cast the variable as a string...

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that's where that error is coming from? I can't seem to make that fail that way here. What does the loop code there look like? Are you using that input/argument in an arithmetic context `$((...))` anywhere?

Comment: Show us where you **use** that value.

Comment: When quoting error messages, don't abbreviate it with `...`.  Show us the exact complete error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're looping over array values, but then trying to use the array *value* as an array *index*:

Here's an example of that:

```
MyArray=(21000E1)
REPLY="FOO21000E1FOO"
for i in "${MyArray[@]}"
do
  if [[ $REPLY == *${MyArray[$i]}* ]]
  then
    echo "found"
  fi
done
```

This results in:

```
bash: 21000E1: value too great for base (error token is "21000E1")
```

Here are three ways of referencing the same value:

```
$i              # Correct, uses value directly
${MyArray[0]}   # Correct, looks up value using the value's index
${MyArray[$i]}  # WRONG,   tries to look up value using value as index
```

Since `$i` is already the value and not the index, just use it directly:

```
MyArray=(21000E1)
REPLY="FOO21000E1FOO"
for i in "${MyArray[@]}"
do
  if [[ $REPLY == *"$i"* ]]
  then
    echo "found"
  fi
done
```

This results in `found`.

Comment: I see... I didn't realize the value of $i is the element and not the index! A rookie mistake :) Thanks for spotting the issue.